# Compactness of the graph of a function from a compact domain implies its continuity.

Tags: general-topology

Prove or disprove the following statement.

> Let $X$ be a $T_2$ topological space and $E$ be a compact subset of $X$. Let us define $f:E \rightarrow R$ be a mapping such that the set $\{(x,f(x)):x \in E\}$ is compact. Then $f$ is continuous.

I did prove this for a function from $R$ to $R$ by contradiction. To prove that I am assuming the graph is compact (I.e. closed and bounded in that case) and suppose $a$ be a point of discontinuity of $f$. Then I prove the existence of a limit point of the graph which is not in the graph. In this method I did use a lot of things which is not true in an arbitrary topological space. So I'm clueless about the prove of this problem,and also I am unable to find an example to disprove the it.

Comment: The set doesn't make any sense, because $f$ is only defined on $E$? Do you mean $\{(x,f(x))\ |\ x \in E\}$?

Comment: Yes...sorry for my mistake.

Comment: You might as well assume that $X$ is a compact $T_2$ space and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a map. What have you tried?

Comment: I did prove this for a function from R to R by contradiction method. As the graph is compact so it is bounded then assuming a be a point of discontinuity of f then I construct a limit point of the graph which is not in the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be closed in $\mathbb{R}$. If $p_X: E \times \mathbb{R} \to E$ is the (continuous) projection, then $$f^{-1}[C] = p[G_f \cap p^{-1}[C]]$$ where $G_f = \{(x,f(x)): x \in E\}$ is our compact graph. It follows that $G_f \cap p^{-1}[C]$ is also compact (being closed in $G_f$) and thus $f^{-1}[C]$ is also compact in $E$ (as the continuous image of a compact set), and so closed (as $X$ is Hausdorff). As $C$ was any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ we see that $f$ is continuous (as the inverse image of a closed set is always closed).

Note that I only used Hausdorffness on $X$, no properties of $E$ nor $\mathbb{R}$.